# Apache 2.4 security of mod_session_crypto

Tags: apache-2.4

I have an apache 2.4 server configured with `mod_auth_form`, `mod_session` and `mod_session_crypto` for encrypting the contents of the session cookie.

If I'm not mistaken, the default encryption should be using OpenSSL and aes256 cypher. This is an asymmetric cypher which uses private and public keys. I do not quite understand the `SessionCryptoPassphrase` directive. What is this passphrase used for exactly? The docs state the following:

> The SessionCryptoPassphrase directive specifies the keys to be used to enable **symmetrical** encryption on the contents of the session before writing the session, or decrypting the contents of the session after reading the session.

Finally, my question is how secure are the cookies encrypted this way? They still contain the username and password, only it's encrypted. Can a hacker crack this and gain access to the data inside? Will the knowledge of this passphrase allow the hacker to gain the info inside the cookies?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/winlibs/apache/blob/master/2.4.x/modules/session/mod_session_crypto.c#L156 uses https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr-util/1.6/group___a_p_r___util___crypto.html#ga98dea2011c0e173ab1f059c5a9ea8b14 which generates the key from the supplied passphrase. I'm unclear how the IV is set/determined, but they use CBC mode at least, so it appears to be secure enough.

Unfortunately for me, I'd like to share the cookie with another backend application, and trying to use `mod_session_dbd` appears to be easier than replicating the KDF exactly, even with the same passphrase.